# How to fail an Azure Automation Runbook?

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

Is there any way to make an Azure Automation Runbook end with a status of 'Failed'? Even when exceptions are thrown, the runbook still ends in a status of 'Complete'. You can go into the runbook job with status of "Complete" and see the exceptions thrown.

However, is there a way to explicitly fail an Azure Runbook, for example if you catch an exception and want the entire runbook to fail, so that the status will end in "Failed"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `catch` block, you need to use `throw` statement again.

Sample code in runbook:

```
try
{
   $wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
   $wc.DownloadFile("http://www.contoso.com/MyDoc.doc")
}
catch
{
    # explicitly use throw here
    throw "I have some errors."
}
```

After running completed, in the job status:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I use $errorActionPreference = "Stop" in all PowerShell scripts, including Azure Automation Runbooks otherwise normal PowerShell handling ("Continue") will cause errors to not be handled and reported.